# Writing Python batch script for Analyze and Compress on ArcSDE Geodatabases?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I created and modified python scripts based off of ERSI's example (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000v7000000), however, what would be great is to be able to batch process these files using python.

I attempted trying ModelBuilder by adding two database connections to the compress tool. (That didn't work.) Obviously, right-clicking on the tool in ArcToolbox brings up the option for batch, but I have no idea how to do this for python.

I can not seem to find anywhere the ability to do this. It's a pain to have ten scripts running the same thing but with different databases.

Anyone know how to do this with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a variable for each connection and then add these variable to a list

```
ws1 = r'D:\Temp\conn1.sde'
ws2 = r'D:\Temp\conn2.sde'
ws3 = r'D:\Temp\conn3.sde'
WSS = [ws1,ws2,ws3]
for ws in WSS:
    arcpy.RebuildIndexes_management(ws, "SYSTEM", dataList, "ALL")
    arcpy.AnalyzeDatasets_management(ws, "SYSTEM", dataList, "ANALYZE_BASE",  "ANALYZE_DELTA", "ANALYZE_ARCHIVE")
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you create a python list with your 10 different database connections?  Then loop through the list:

```
for db in databases:
    #connect to db
    #compress db
    #disconnect from db
```

You might need a dictionary if your connection properties differ for each database.
http://yuji.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/python-basics-of-python-dictionary-and-looping-through-them/